# Copiar um arquivo do servidor para uma pasta local

Tags: c#

Estou desenvolvendo uma rotina com o objetivo de copiar arquivos do servidor para uma pasta local, mas, infelizmente não copia. A ideia é que há cada um minuto os arquivos sejam copiados.

Deixei um `Sleep(5000)` menor para facilitar o teste. Não tem domínio no servidor e a pasta no servidor está mapeada. Poderiam dar uma olhada?

Código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsService1
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            ThreadStart start = new ThreadStart(CopiarArquivo);

            Thread thread = new Thread(start);

            thread.Start();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
        }

        public void CopiarArquivo()
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < 600; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);

            File.Copy(@"Z:\PARAM.SAC", @"C:\SACTRM\PARAM.SAC");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual erro está ocorrendo ? É possível que o usuário que executa o programa não tenha permissão de acessar a pasta mapeada.

Comment: Olá Rafael. Fiz uma outra rotina faz um acesso à pasta no servidor e exibe o nome do arquivo em questa na tela. Funcionou perfeitamente, por isso não estou considerando a possibilidade de permissão.

Comment: Não mostra nenhum erro, simplesmente não copia.

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente o problema é a permissão. Mesmo que não tenha domínio no servidor, você pode criar um usuário local em cada computador, mas o nome e senha devem ser iguais em ambos os computadores. Depois execute a aplicação com esse usuário, o windows interpreta que é o mesmo usuário. Não esqueça de dar permissão de leitura (Arquivo no servidor) e escrita(pasta destino) a esse usuário.

Answer (score 0):

Pode utilizar a nomenclatura [UNC](https://www.lifewire.com/unc-universal-naming-convention-818230) nos caminhos.

```
File.Copy(@"\\SVR\PARAM.SAC", @"C:\SACTRM\PARAM.SAC")
```

Também ficar atento a permissões de leitura no arquivo de origem e de escrita ao caminho de destino.

Answer (score 0):

A mesma rotina, só que ao invés de um Windpws Service utilizei um Windows Form. Funcionou. Só que necessito que seja um serviço. Não tentei a solução sua Rafael pois não gostaria de utilizar usuários. Mas mesmo com este teste com WF acha ainda necessário configurar usuários ?. Obrigado.